# Manually check if Laravel middleware is passed

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

Assume I have 2 routes:

```
Route::get('/viewfile', 'FileController@view');

// second route has 2 middlewares which could be anything else (dynamic)
Route::get('/upload', [
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'upload'], 
    'uses' => 'FileController@upload'
]);
```

Now when a user (or a visitor) visits `/viewfile`, need to check if it is also able to pass all the middlewares assigned to `/upload` route.

In another words, how to check if `/upload` route is also accessible?

Comment: Use an authorization gate (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization) and check that.

Comment: It was informative, but it changes issue totally and needs some changes in app architecture.